# Как сделать кнопку лаунчера кликабельной?

Tags: java

Я имею вот такой код:

```
    int lrh = 20;
    int irw = 220;
    passfield1 = new TButton();
    passfield1.setBounds(0, 45, irw, lrh);
    passfield1.setText("Список изменений");
    passfield1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    tifields.add(passfield1);
```

Прошу вас, пожалуйста, сделайте так, чтобы из при нажатии на эту кнопку открывалась ссылка на сайт, допустим, google.ru/search

Answer (score 1):

[Решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10037644/opening-a-url-from-a-jbutton-in-simple-java-program).

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете воспользоваться данным кодом:

```
passfield1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         try{
            Desktop d = Desktop.getDesktop();
            d.browse(new URI("https://www.google.ru"));
        }catch( IOException | URISyntaxException ex){}
    }
});
```

UPD: Пардон. Только заметил, что вопрос задан 5 лет назад XD